# Can't get the text inside label tags inside jquery-ajax function

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, label

I have the following JQuery/AJAX code:

```
  $("button#submit").click(function () {

        var form = $('#pick-status-form');
        var selectedStatusID = form.find('input[name=statusesList]:checked').val();
        //Get the last checked value of the Radio Button

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "updateStatusID.php",
            data: { 'refID': lastRefId,
                'statusID': selectedStatusID
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                var selectedText = $.trim($('input:radio:checked').parent('label').text());
                alert(selectedText); 
           //Get the text next to the radio button

                $("button.btn.btn-default,button.btn.btn-primary").removeClass("disabled");              
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
    $("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

The following code:

```
  var selectedText = $.trim($('input:radio:checked').parent('label').text());
                alert(selectedText);
```

Works great in the following function :

```
$('.statuses-list').change(function () {
    var selectedText = $.trim($('input:radio:checked').parent('label').text());
    alert(selectedText); 
});
```

But when I put it in the AJAX function it doesn't work (get a null alert).
My question is how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    data: { 
            'refID': lastRefId,
             'statusID': selectedStatusID
          },
```

What is lastRefId ? Open your console in browser , I think you will get the js error